# insert entries in multiple tables in php

Tags: php, mysql

I found this tutorial at tizag.com. But It is for displaying entries from different tables.
How can I do an insert?

```
         <?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
   // Construct our join query
      $query = "SELECT family.Position, food.Meal ".
      "FROM family, food ".
"WHERE family.Position = food.Position";

      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


      // Print out the contents of each row into a table 
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['Position']. " - ". $row['Meal'];
echo "<br />";
      }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean inserting data into multiple database tables with one query?
**You can't.**

Read the [MySQL INSERT syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Of course you can loop over your data and e.g. insert it into various tables step by step, but without *real* code from your side it is hard to help.

Comment: thanks, I never thought that the usual insert statement would do. It's just adding 2 sql queries for inserting in 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are a tutorial on same site: [SQL Tutorial - Insert](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlinsert.php)

This can also be useful: [PHP MySQL Insert Into](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_insert.asp)